# Is it possible to open Chrome's databases.db in another MacBook?

Tags: passwords, databases, chrome, macos

According to [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/339281/where-does-chrome-store-login-credentials-in-macos), Chrome passwords are stored in `/Users/$USER/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/databases/Databases.db`. Is it possible for an attacker to copy Chrome passwords found in `Databases.db` and view them on another MacBook?